# How to prevent iOS 10 apps from "resetting" when activated after being backgrounded?

Tags: ios, applications, application-switcher, multitasking

Sometimes, I'll get a notification for an interesting story on the Medium app, tap it, opening the story in Medium, but then get interrupted, so I switch to another app, putting Medium in the background. If I'm especially busy, it may stay backgrounded like this for several hours, until I have time to read the story.

Unfortunately, what happens when I bring Medium to the front later is that it "resets" itself to a default landing page, making it difficult to find the story again (the notification is "cleared" by tapping it, so I don't have it to reopen the story.

This happens in other apps, too: I open a specific content item, background the app for some time, then returning to it, only to have my content item replaced by whatever default screen the app *thinks* I should want to look at.

Is there a way to tell these apps to just open right were I was and stop trying to "help" me so darn much?

I suspect it may have something to do with background refresh or whatever it's called… Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Follow-up: Turning off "background refresh" for Medium did not resolve this issue. After leaving an article open in the background overnight, visiting the app this morning "reset" itself again to the home screen. There may be nothing for it.

Comment: Until the last ios update I could press the home button, launch an app, then hit home, then go back to the other app and it would be exactly where I left it. Now a great many apps including FaceBook don't do this. What a major fail on Apple's part.

Comment: @WilliamS Thanks for your comment: I learned recently that killing apps that you've started (but are not actively using) on iOS is unnecessary thanks to iOS's impressive modern multitasking. People once believed that you needed to kill inactive apps (as on Android) to save battery and memory. Very few apps do anything when backgrounded, so they "wake up" and update themselves when brought to the fore after a while. I imagine it's possible to code an app to reactivate right as you left it, but most don't: it's the price we pay for the ability to leave tons of apps "running" in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is due to the restrictions iOS places on app developers.**

Apps are only allowed to stay open in the background for a few minutes (this saves RAM), so if the developer doesn't have the app save where you were last, the app will reset to its start page. So no, you can't do anything about this.

This is why you don't *really* need to close your apps in the app switcher.

Comment: I appreciate this thorough answer. I guess I'll start bookmarking instead of opening and forgetting interesting posts in Medium (and other apps that provide a way to save state).

Comment: @DaveLand This is a bug in the Medium app then or at least you need to ask the developer to add saving state

Answer (score -3):

use this func on AppDelegate

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldSaveSecureApplicationState coder: NSCoder) -> Bool {
       return true
}
func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldRestoreSecureApplicationState coder: NSCoder) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: Sort of the correct answer but the question is from a user not a developer so not useful

Comment: Thank you, Awad, but as @mmmmmm notes, I was asking from an end-user perspective. I suspect that your answer is the fix that Medium (and some other apps) need to implement.